# How to connect Codeigniter-4 and SQLserver database?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv, codeigniter-4

I have an application developed using **CodeIgniter-4** and connected with **mysql** database which perfectly running. Now I want to run this web application on SQLserver locally but I am getting **Unable to connect to the database** error. Let me show you for better understand what I did in my **Database.php** file

```
    public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'sweater',
    'database' => 'vms_db',
    'DBDriver' => 'sqlsrv',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => false,
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 1433,
];
```

My php version is **7.4.19**. I also downloaded the driver **php_sqlsrv_74_ts_x64.dll** and paste it on **C:\xampp\php\ext** directory.  May be it is a silly mattter but I am not familiar with **SQLserver**. Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong. If you need to know anything about this issue, you are requested to ask me. Thank You for giving your time.

Comment: Did you install both an sql server instance and SSMS? What edition (express, developer, etc.) did you install as your server instance? Can you connect using SSMS? Did you migrate your MySQL database to this new sql server instance? No one can read your mind or see your screen or knows how you reached this point - provide details and context.

Comment: @SMor Yeah. I have installed SQLserver Express and migrated database successfully using SQL server Migration Assistant. I can login SQL server Management studio with credentials which used Database.php file.

Comment: when you do a phpinfo on your application does SQLserver show up in there as a available driver?

Comment: @marcogmonteiro Yeah it;s available.

Comment: Have you tried localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 in your hostname?

Comment: @marcogmonteiro Yes. But It doesn't work.